# Allow private access to Git on shared hosting server

Tags: git, shared-hosting

I've setup my own VM running Ubuntu 10.04, LAMP and ISPConfig 3. I would also like to add Git, and give access to to closed group of developers working on their own private projects, essentially operating it as a shared hosting production server.

Before I go installing software on the server gung-ho, I would like to know;

**a)** Is this possible?

**b)** Is it a good idea? (How else could one achieve a shared but private environment?)

**c)** Is the installation of Git any different in this situation?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite#readme), it is probably the easiest way to set up a shared Git environment (I assume you have SSH access and full control over your VM). Gitolite uses SSH keys to authenticate users and allows to set up privilege separation.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Looks like that's what I was after.